# What remains after removing leaves and roots from a directed graph?

Tags: graphs

Suppose I start with a directed graph, and remove any leaf nodes, and then repeatedly remove leaf nodes from the now-modified graph until there are no more leaves. Then I repeatedly remove root nodes as well. What is the remaining graph when there are no more roots or leaves? (Assuming it's not empty.)

I have an idea that any remaining subgraph is the "loopy part", which, I guess, must contain any cycles in the original graph. Is there a name or very short description of  this loopy part?

Comment: It's a graph without indegree or outdegree zero vertices.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a particular name for this. Indeed, each cycle is contained in this graph, but there also could be some vertices which are not in any cycle, so I am not so sure about the "loopy" name.

For example, consider the following graph. No vertex is removed using your transformation, but the vertex $4$ is not in any cycle.

[image]